# Is this the best place to ask complex questions?

Tags: discussion

I've somehow fried my pc trying to install ubuntu and have a lot to write to describe symptoms, etc. Is this where people do that kind of thing or is there somewhere less official where people go for more complex questions?

Comment: If it's on topic, go ahead and ask it

Comment: Ask Ubuntu is a *Question and Answer* site, so if you have a question you can ask it, and people will provide answers if they can. Each post is intended for a single question, so if you have multiple problems, they can be asked in multiple threads (ie. one question per post).  Other alternatives exist; eg. [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/) is a traditional forum  allowing more *discussion* or multi-part complex threads, but many find forum/threads harder as they often get long (*why Q&A format exists*)

Comment: If "fried my pc trying to install ubuntu" you can describe the symptoms in great detail and we help you get your PC **to boot again** in answers and comments. But we will close as too broad if you ask "How do I get X11 graphics and PulseAudio sound to work again?", which should be 2 questions. Please use the search bar too

Answer (score 5):

If possible, break your complex problem into several smaller, simpler problems, each asked separately.

AskUbuntu works best with simple, answerable questions: "How do I troubleshoot XYZ?" or "What does XYZ mean?"

If you need interactive help (i.e. lots of followup questions), then [IRC](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IRC/ChannelList) or [UbuntuForums](http://www.ubuntuforums.org) might be a better fit.

Don't forget to try the search bar with each simpler question. Maybe it was asked already. And answered. If you discover a newer or better answer, add it to that question!